# xsl:sort not sorting data

Tags: xml, xslt

I need the following xml to sort on the id field:

```
<top>
<repeat1>
    <repeat2>
        <contents>
            <contentitem>
                <id>9</id>
                <moretags1/>
                <moretags2/>
            </contentitem>
        </contents>
    </repeat2>
</repeat1>
<repeat1>
    <repeat2>
        <contents>
            <contentitem>
                <id>6</id>
                <moretags1/>
                <moretags2/>
            </contentitem>
        </contents>
    </repeat2>
</repeat1>
<repeat1>
    <repeat2>
        <contents>
            <contentitem>
                <id>3</id>
                <moretags1/>
                <moretags2/>
            </contentitem>
        </contents>
    </repeat2>
</repeat1>
</top>
```

to so be sorted like this:

```
<top>
<repeat1>
    <repeat2>
        <contents>
            <contentitem>
                <id>3</id>
                <moretags1/>
                <moretags2/>
            </contentitem>
        </contents>
    </repeat2>
</repeat1>
<repeat1>
    <repeat2>
        <contents>
            <contentitem>
                <id>6</id>
                <moretags1/>
                <moretags2/>
            </contentitem>
        </contents>
    </repeat2>
</repeat1>
<repeat1>
    <repeat2>
        <contents>
            <contentitem>
                <id>9</id>
                <moretags1/>
                <moretags2/>
            </contentitem>
        </contents>
    </repeat2>
</repeat1>
 </top>
```

In other words, I want the contentitem grouping to remain intact but list out in the resulting xml in order by id.  I'm trying to use the following xsl but not having any luck.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<!--                                                -->
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<!--                                                -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<!--                                                -->
<xsl:template match="contents">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="contentitem">
            <xsl:sort select="id" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you should be sorting the `repeat1` elements, rather than the `contents` elements here.

Try this XSLT instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="top">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="repeat1">
            <xsl:sort select="repeat2/contents/contentitem/id" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```